# How to index this situation?

Tags: solr

I have the following database of words and synonyms, for example:

```
Word|Synonyms
flower|['tulip', 'flora', 'rose', etc]
rose | ['lily', 'flower', 'tulip', 'hydranga']
tulip | [etc...]
```

I'm new to Solr and would like to know how best to index this and run a query such that if I searched for tulip it would return all the keys where it had a value of tulip inside the list of synonyms

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Index each synonym list as a single document:

```
{
  "word": "flower",
  "synonyms": ["tulip", "flora", "rose"]
}
```

You can then query for any words that have "tulip" among their synonyms by issuing a query like `synonyms:tulip` (i.e. `q=synonyms:tulip`).